# Combine two parallel lines to one with postgis

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapnik, generalization

In OpenStreetMap, a highway=motorway consists out of two parallel lines, each representing one direction:

[image: Two lines in parallel]

On a professional map the two lanes get combined to one single line and drawn with a middle line:

[image]

Is there an easy way with postgis functions to combine that two lines to one in between to be able to render the highway accordingly? It has to be considered that the two lanes could split somewhere and every direction has to be rendered separately again (e.g. for going around a mountain). So there needs to be a parameter to set the maximum distance between both lines.

Comment: Yes, this is quite the same question. I guess a solution is not as easy as calling just a PostGIS function.

Comment: The answer of the duplicate question is not satisfying. Perhaps the problem can't be solved.